# Why is my CPU usage is this high no heavy load?

Tags: cpu, performance, cpu-usage, idle

[image]

This picture happens mostly at the time after starting the computer while it is almost idle. CPU usage goes around 80-100 for out of nothing. The performance mode of the fans were on but seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: You should click the CPU header twice to sort by descending order, then post a new screenshot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

After starting up, WD does scans. That is very normal.

Your machine is also checking for updates.  That too is normal.

Let it run for several hours, run updates, restart and it should be well.

From what I can see, nothing to worry about.

Comment: "WD" =?=> Windows Defender == Antimalware Service Exe...

Comment: Windows Defender runs a service called Antimalware Service

Comment: Yes; not obvious on the first glance. ;-]